# How to retrieve the full name of an acrofield with pdfbox

Tags: java, pdfbox

I have a pdf with acroform fields, now I need to find the corresponding PDField Objects. 
For that I am using this code

```
public PDField getPDFieldWithName(final String fieldname){
    PDDocumentCatalog docCatalog = pdDocument.getDocumentCatalog();
    PDAcroForm acroForm = docCatalog.getAcroForm();
    return acroForm.getFields().stream()
                        .filter( x -> x.getPartialName().equalsIgnoreCase(fieldname))
                        .findFirst()
                        .get();
}
```

This works for normal fields, but if the fields on the pdfs are grouped with dots and one of those fields are used, it does not work.

As I could see PDFBox handles such fields as PDNonTerminalField, is there a easy way to get the latest child and check against it?

On my form there is a field named Test.foo.bar when I search with the above method for a field with name "Test.foo.bar" it does not find it

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getFields` only returns the root fields. The better solution would be to call `getFieldIterator()`. Or just call `getField(fullyQualifiedName)` if you have the full name.

Comment: Sometimes its too easy, just finished my recursive version to handle the child fields and such stuff, did not see this way. Thanks, I will use this version.